# Creating and modifying calendar subscriptions using the google API

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want the ability to create a calendar using the calendar API and issue one-way syncs to this calendar when changes happen on my end. I do not want the user to be able to make changes, i.e., it should work like a subscription but instead of google pulling changes, I want to push changes. This way users can get the changes in real time as opposed to having to wait for a long time to see updates.

I looked through the APIs and I could find no way to a) create subscription b) force subscribed calendar refresh. I also tried creating a secondary calendar and setting ACLs on it for the current user but this also doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
"reason": "cannotChangeOwnAcl",
"message": "Cannot change your own access level."
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with the API?

Comment: specifying read-only scopes will help with the user not being able to make changes, but you'll have to create the Calendar beforehand. An alternative is for you to implement access roles (admin, users, etc) that can have read/write scopes and read-only scopes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide an example on how to do this? I am not very familiar with scopes. The problem I think I am having is that I am authenticated as the user, so even though I create the calendar, I cannot ACL it as it would effectively reduce my own permissions.